# Google Maps with Bootstrap not responsive

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I embedded Google Maps API 3.

`#map_canvas` isn't responsive; it's a fixed width.

Also, if I use `height: auto` and `width: auto` the map doesn't show up in the page.

Why?

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
#map_canvas {
   height: 400px;
    width: auto;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
   <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

***REVISED: The Official Post is outdated, so I've updated my answer and improved the code.***

The following method **does not require bootstrap or any other framework**. It can be used independently to make any content responsive.  To the parent element is applied a padding by calculating the [`aspect ratio`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio). Then the child element is placed on top using absolute position.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="iframe-container">
    <!-- embed code here -->
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.iframe-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
}
.iframe-container > *{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

The following 'fiddle' has examples on how to make:

- **Responsive Google Map**
- **Responsive OpenStreetMap**
- **Responsive Vimeo Video**
- **Responsive Youtube Video**

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LHQQZ/135/

Comment: the first method works but when I change the height to 100% does'nt show up can you tell me please why?

Comment: Method 3 worked great for me.  I'm using Bootstrap 3 and gmaps4rails 1.x.

Comment: Worked for me on PHP and HTML. Thanks.

Comment: there is no need to use iframe any state, in my case i used this class with div and everything ok! thank u

Answer (score 27):

This uses Bootstrap's [Responsive Embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) feature with fixed aspect ratio of 16/9:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="embed-responsive-item" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ensure your code uses a recall to the libraries on window resize by adding a DOM Listener as well.

Comment: This still works with Bootstrap 4.0 Beta. It is critical you put the `iframe` code within the `embed-responsive-item` div. Thank you for posting this solution. This should be the correct answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 10):

makes the map resize in both height and width:

http://niklausgerber.com/blog/responsive-google-or-bing-maps/

2018/09/27 update: link is reportedly down, not sure for how much, so I'll link my web archive search to his github:

https://github.com/niklausgerber/responsive-google-or-bing-maps

Comment: some code should be in the answer in case the link goes down

Comment: web archive is our friend :)

Answer (score 10):

Extremely simple. Make the map relative to viewport height using CSS:

```
.map {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

This specifies that the .map container must be 80% of the viewport height.

Comment: This seemed to be the fix for me. I tried all the other responses and nothing worked. Especially because I had mine within a `row` in a `col-md-xx`

Comment: This works like a charm in bootstrap 4 and rails 5.2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If someone else look this, had a problem like that.

I had an iframe whit an openstreet map, and i couldn't make it responsive. I finally put a "img-responsive" class and all was good.

```
<iframe class="img-responsive" width="350" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="YOUR OPENSTREET URL HERE" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I believe the simplest answer is the one that @chech posted, that worked for me in every browser I've checked, even on my phone and tablet.

Answer (score 2):

## 09 2021

It's been 8yrs since the question is asked.
If any of you still looking for the solution and couldn't find it, here it is.

### Boostrap 5 (tested and works)

Add `width="100%"` to the Google Map `iframe`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <iframe src="SOURCE" width="100%" OTHER_ATTRIBUTES></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: genial! bootstrap 5 so simple

Answer (score 1):

For those embedding using the javascript api (not iframe):

```html
<div class="googleMapContainer">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.googleMapContainer {
    position: relative;
    &:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the `span6` class a width and height, then give `map_canvas` a width and height of `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Smartik's answer works well.. I am using the gmaps4rails gem and applied these changes to the generated css like this:

```
.map_container {
padding: 6px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
display: block;
}

.gmaps4rails_map {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Then added these lines to my view:

```
<div class="map_container">
  <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map">
    <div id="map_canvas" class="span9">
      <%= gmaps({"map_options" => { "type" => "ROADMAP", "center_longitude" => 180,"auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 16, "auto_adjust" => true}, "markers" => { "data" => @json }})%>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="map_container">
    <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map">
        <div id="map_canvas" class="span9">
            <%= gmaps({"map_options" => { "type" => "ROADMAP", "center_longitude" => 180,"auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 16, "auto_adjust" => true}, "markers" => { "data" => @json }})%>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are never good, especially poorly formatted ones.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/responsive-google-maps/) has a great solution.

> Add a div tag around the embed code. Use the CSS class map-responsive
>   so that your code now looks like this:

```
<div class="map-responsive">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d386950.6511603643!2d-73.70231446529533!3d40.738882125234106!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNueva+York!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sus!4v1445032011908" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

> Now add some CSS properties inside one of your stylesheet files:

```
.map-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.map-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```